# How to use auto layout so that the following layout is achieved?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I have a vertical `UIStackView` whose top, leading and trailing edges are pinned to the superview and whose height is determined by its subviews.

Its arranged subviews consist of 5 horizontal `UIStackView`s each of which have 3 `UILabel`s as their arranged subviews.

For each of the horizontal `UIStackView`, the text of the first `UILabel` is the heading, the text of the second `UILabel` is the colon and the text of the third `UILabel` is the info as shown in the following image

[image: The image of the layout]

All of the `UILabel`s have `numberOfLines` = `0` so that they are multiline.

I would like to create constraints using auto layout so that the following conditions are met-

1. The colon `UILabel`s are all vertically aligned
2. The width of the info `UILabel`s are at least 20% of parent view
3. The width of the info `UILabel`s are at most 60% of parent view
4. If the width of all the info `UILabel`s is less than 60% of parent view ( see 3 ), then it must shrink to the width of the widest info `UILabel`.

I understand how to use auto layout to create constraints to satisfy the first 3 conditions.

However, I do not understand how to create constraint to satisfy the 4th condition. I tried increasing the "Content Hugging Priority" but it shrinks the label to 20% of the parent view ( see 2 ).

Can anyone point out how to achieve this layout?

Comment: Your "Heading" labels are also set to `numberOfLines = 0`? Meaning, they may also need to word-wrap?

Comment: And... are you always going to have 5 "rows"? Or will that be dynamic?

Comment: Yes, the heading labels may also word-wrap. There are always going to be 5 rows.

Comment: It's not clear, but I'm assuming you want the results to be in aligned "columns" as opposed to each "row" laying itself out? In other words, you want the ***top*** image, not the ***bottom*** image here: https://imgur.com/a/Jl9TC0o ?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, you are correct. I want the top image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is considerably more complex than it would appear on the surface.

The "Info" column has to be evaluated for min/max width and word-wrapping, and the "Heading" column has to be evaluated for word-wrapping based on the "Info" columns variable width... ***and*** the "Info" labels have to match widths based on the widest wrapped (or not) text.

That's a lot for auto-layout to handle.

I don't *think* it can be done with constraints only. The main problem being that auto-layout calculates the height of the height of the Heading labels based on the *potential* for the Info labels to be at their widest.

So, we can end up with this:

[image]

and the Heading label text is no longer vertically aligned to the top of the label.

The best I could come up with is to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, using a counter which forces auto-layout to calculate the Info labels first and then the Heading labels.

As to constraint settings...

The Heading labels need nothing special - just set the number of lines to Zero to allow word-wrapping.

The "Colon" labels don't need constraints, but they do need both Horizontal Content Hugging and Compression Resistance set to `1000` (required), because we don't want them stretching or getting squeezed.

The Info labels need:

- Horizontal Content Compression Resistance: 1000
- Horizontal Content Hugging: 999
- Width: >= its stackView Width with Multiplier 0.2
- Width: <= its stackView Width with Multiplier 0.6
- Width: = its stackView Width with Multiplier 0.2 and Priority: 999

and finally, the *bottom* 4 Info labels need Width constraint equal to the *top* Info label.

The horizontal stack views that make up the 5 "rows" should be set to:

- Alignment: Top
- Distribution: Fill
- Spacing: 8  (horizontal spacing between the "columns")

The vertical stack view that holds the 5 "rows" should be set to:

- Alignment: Fill
- Distribution: Fill
- Spacing: 10  (vertical spacing between the "rows")

I've put up a project on GitHub that demonstrates the layout -- it has 10 different "variations" of label content to show how the sizing works: https://github.com/DonMag/MutlilineVarWidthLabelColumns

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this kind of UI by using min and max constraints.
you can follow the below constraints for it.

1. give `max width` to `Heading label` with the relation of the screen.
2. give `fix width` to `colon label`
3. Give `leading`, `trailing`, `top`, `bottom` to `info label`
4. change **Horizontal** `content hugging priority` of info Label to **252**.

please check the below images for more details.

The actual structure of my example

[image]

Constraints for Heading label

[image]

Constraints for info-label

[image]

output

[image]

If you need any help then feel free to ask again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this solution is that it does not satisfy the fourth condition given in the question. Make the text of one of the info labels longer than the other. You will see that the text of the info label wraps but the width of the info labels become lesser than 60% of superview.

Comment: I think you cannot check the condition like if `lesser then 60%` but you can put max validation and assign the same max width to all other labels.